# Symfony + MongoDB driver issue

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, pecl

I'm following [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html) tutorial, but Symfony doesn't seem to find the `MongoId` class.

```
{
    "message": "Attempted to load class \"MongoId\" from the global namespace.\nDid you forget a \"use\" statement?",
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ClassNotFoundException",
    "trace": [
      {
        "namespace": "",
        "short_class": "",
        "class": "",
        "type": "",
        "function": "",
        "file": "/home/local/BROCELIA/kha/dev/symfonyTraining/rest/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Id/AutoGenerator.php",
        "line": 34,
        "args": []
      },
      ...
    ]
}
```

Here's my Document:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Product
{
/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="float")
 */
protected $price;

public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
}

public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}

public function setPrice($price) {
    $this->price = $price;
    return $this;
}

public function getPrice() {
    return $this->price;
}
}
```

And here's my Controller: (NB: I'm using PhPStorm and it doesn't seem to find the `persist()` and `flush()` methods either. Don't know how it could be related though).

```
    <?php
    namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Controller;

    use Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Product;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

    class DefaultController extends Controller
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {
            return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
        }


        public function createAction()
        {
            $product = new Product();
            $product->setName('A Foo Bar');
            $product->setPrice('19.99');
            $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
            $dm->persist($product);
            $dm->flush();
            return new Response('Created product id '.$product->getId());
        }
    }
```

My php version being `PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )`. I installed the php MongoDB driver through pecl. I also added `extension=mongodb.so` at the end of my php.ini (I had two of these: `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini`, I added it in both). `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep "mongo"` outputs this:

```
mongodb
mongodb support => enabled
mongodb version => 1.1.9
mongodb stability => stable
libmongoc version => 1.3.6
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

So I'm guessing the driver is installed. Although there's no such thing as mongodb.ini (or even mongo.ini) in the output of php --ini;

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
... Lots of .ini but nothing mongo-related.
```

4 hours and still no idea of where I messed up. I tried and reinstalled the mongodb driver, php and pecl several times, in vain. The other posts on SO asking for this seem to have fixed their issues by a simple reinstall of the driver. Sadly wasn't my case, plus I'm new into symfony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to run `composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle`, composer was red-angry, telling me I don't have the mongodb extension. Although I have it, it seems that doctrine/mongodb requires `ext-mongo` and not `mongodb`. `ext-mongo` only works for php versions <= 5.6. Seems like [this package](https://packagist.org/packages/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter) might be able to do the trick though.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your entity.

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Id;
```

So:

```
namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Product
{
   /**
    * @MongoDB\Id
    */
   protected $id;
```

### **EDIT**

This is how you install it in your app.

**Composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev"
    },
}
```

**Composer update**

```
php composer.phar update doctrine/mongodb-odm doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle
```

**Autoload.php**

```
# app/autoload.php
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;
AnnotationDriver::registerAnnotationClasses();
```

**AppKernel.php**

```
new Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle(),
```

**Configuration**

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server:  mongodb://localhost:27017
            options: {}

    default_database: your_mongodb_database
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping:  true
            retry_connect: 3
            retry_query:   3
```

**Make sure your mongo is running**

```
$ mongod
```

Look at [Simple doctrine mongodb CRUD example in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/htk5/simple-doctrine-mongodb-crud-example-in-symfony) for the example.

Comment: Still the same error message :/ - Shouldn't the `use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;` used as `MongoDB\Id` actually be the same thing ?

Comment: Answer updated. The blog has more examples with with symfony+mongo.

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/bjuNaVwx) is the output I get from composer.phar. Looks like it doesnt even see the mongo php extension. All the rest of what you specified is already into my code, also, mongodb is running, on the good port.

Comment: They are related to your OS environment not the app itself.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is why composer doesn't see my mongodb driver installed.